# SET NAMES or setEncoding utf8 in RedBeanPHP?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am using [REDBEANPHP 3.5 | easy ORM for PHP](http://redbeanphp.com/) and working with me for all parts in my app but now I have a problem while select data from database with Arabic content via

```
    R::setup('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    $sql = "select * from comments";
    $comments = R::getAll($sql);
    echo "<pre>";
    die(print_r($comments));
```

I am getting data as

```
  ["comment_content"]=> "ØªØ¬Ø±Ø¨Ø© Ù…Ù…ØªØ§Ø²Ø© ÙˆØªØ³ØªØ­Ù‚ Ø§Ù„ØªÙƒØ±Ø§Ø±"
```

I am searching for that and know default encoding in REDBEANPHP is UTF8 also found setEncoding function called inside RedBean_Driver_PDO class if you use the following way

```
  try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        $dbh->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
        $driver = new RedBean_Driver_PDO($dbh);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $comments = $driver->GetAll($sql);
    echo "<pre>";
    die(print_r($comments));
```

But Still same output

```
  ["comment_content"]=> "ØªØ¬Ø±Ø¨Ø© Ù…Ù…ØªØ§Ø²Ø© ÙˆØªØ³ØªØ­Ù‚ Ø§Ù„ØªÙƒØ±Ø§Ø±"
```

I am sure that my db support utf8 because when I am use the following code

```
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "select * from comments";
$result = mysql_query($sql) ;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    (print_r($row));
}
```

I am getting correct data as

```
[comment_content] => تجربة ممتازة وتستحق التكرار
```

I am also trying

```
R::exec('SET NAMES utf8');
```

But still no hope so , How can I set that encoding to support Arabic content?

Comment: @deceze no it's not duplicate .. I already create db with urf8 .. this issue inside RedBeanPHP as illustrated above

Comment: If you get Arabic data over a `mysql` connection without setting the encoding (which typically means latin1 encoding), then yes, everything points to the same problem as in the duplicate. Have you tried viewing your database with some 3rd party viewer, like phpMyAdmin or other desktop database utilities? Because those typically get the encoding right. If you see your data as garbage in the database, it is a duplicate. Also see [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: @deceze  Ya Ya Ya your work around work fine but after setting UTF8 as default encoding as 

 R::setup('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ";charset=utf8", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);     
    R::exec('SET NAMES utf8');
    (var_dump(R::getDatabaseAdapter()->getDatabase()->getMysqlEncoding()));    
    $sql = "select * , CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(comment_content USING latin1) USING utf8) as comment_content  from comments ";
    $comments = R::getAll($sql); 

Thanks bro

Comment: It's not a "work around", it's fixing your broken database storage.

Comment: ya I mean "work around" cuz am connecting to website db via api so I cant access db or edit it ,, really your solution is amazing and you are fantastic guru :) really help me .. thanks a lot :)